# How do I set the default month for the angular-ui/ui-calendar for AngularJS(ver 1)? By default, it sets it to the current month

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui, ui-calendar

After having read the fullcalendar docs, I thought setting a month attribute in calendar in $scope.uiConfig as below would do it. But I can't understand where exactly I set the month attribute in.

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: { 
        firstDay:1,
        month: 0,
        year: 2018, 
        height: 220,
        aspectRatio: 1.09,
        editable: true,
        header:{ 
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: '' 
        },
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick, 
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
        month: 3 
    } 
};
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but you have set month to both 0 and 3. Perhaps that is causing your issue?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. That didn't fix the issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. I used the attribute 'defaultDate' instead of 'month'. This has been updated based on the fullcalendar docs [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultDate). It accepts any moment date. For example:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
calendar:{
 defaultDate: "2018-10-01"
 }
}
```